# Melhor forma de pegar um texto + HTML vindos de um array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Função que estou usando:

```
$(".push-description-top").each(function() {

    var text = $(this).text();
    var carac = text.length;

    if (carac > 0) {
        var query = text.split(" ", 14);
        query.push('<a href="">... Veja mais!</a>');
        res = query.join(' ');
        $(this).text(res);
    }

});
```

Ao puxar o texto e o HTML (`<a href="">... Veja mais!</a>`) da array, o HTML está vindo como texto normal e não no formato HTML.

Comment: Com jQuery acho que nem tem outra forma, e se tem seriam bizarras.

Comment: acontece que ele esta retornando como elemento de texto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para inserir um texto com marcações HTML em um elemento você pode usar `$(this).html(res);` ao invés de `$(this).text(res);`

`$().text()` trata o conteúdo como string enquanto `$().html()` trata a string como HTML.

### Exemplo

```js
$("#div1").html('<a href="/">Diga </a><b>ola</b>');
$("#div2").text('<a href="/">Diga </a><b>ola</b>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Qual é a diferença?

Comment: Editei a resposta @LaércioLopes

Comment: Legal, achei esse exemplo muito bom: http://jsfiddle.net/hossain/sUTVg/

Answer (score 2):

A função `.html(param)` quando passado uma `string HTML` como parâmetro define o conteúdo `HTML` de cada elemento no conjunto de elementos correspondente, ou seja, diferente da [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) que só permite a manipulação de um texto a [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) permite a manipulação de um elemento `HTML`.

Segue exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(".push-description-top").each(function() {

    var text = $(this).text();
    var carac = text.length;

    if (carac > 0) {
        var query = text.split(" ", 14);
        query.push('<a href="">... Veja mais!</a>');
        res = query.join(' ');
        // $(this).text(res); Atribuirá somente um TEXTO
        $(this).html(res); //Criará um link
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="push-description-top">
  
</div>
```